Filter Pane selections issue
I have 4 filter panes. I have created 4 master dimensions to include in each filter panes and one  the expression I have written inside master item is as below
Aggr(If(Only({1}CNLevelOrder) < 13, Replace(Only({1}CNLevelSelect), 'No. of days', 'Days')), CNLevelSelect)
Like the above expression I have 3 other master item dimensions
The problem I'm facing is when I'm selecting one value from 1st filter pane and selecting another value from 2nd filter pane , 1st filter pane values are deselecting out. This should not happen
The other filter pane selection should also show when I select value from current filter pane
Please help, Thanks!!
I tried the expression below to create master dimension and used same dimension in filter pane
Aggr(If(Only({1}CNLevelOrder) < 13, Replace(Only({1}CNLevelSelect), 'No. of days', 'Days')), CNLevelSelect)
